# Making a account system with text boxes and buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a login system with a text box and a button.  You are supposed to enter the password into the text box and then press the button but when I do this nothing happens.  Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function EnterPwerd() {
var pass= input = document.getElementById("text")
if ( (pass=='bacon') ) {
document.write("BACON is so good.")
}
else {
document.write("You put the wrong password you taco biscuit!")
}
</script>
<div id="text"><input type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="15"></civ>
<input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="EnterPwerd()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your closing div is a typo (</civ>)
You can better do as
Add an id of textbox
<div id="text"><input type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="15" id= "pwd"></div>

hold password as
var pass= document.getElementById("pwd")

also for password use type="password" to hide letters
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the input elements value, you need to get the input elements id.
Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function EnterPwerd() {
            var pass = document.getElementById("text").value;
            if ( (pass=='bacon') ) {
                document.write("BACON is so good.");
            }
            else {
                document.write("You put the wrong password you taco biscuit!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="15"  id="text">
    <input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="EnterPwerd()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thnks That will really help!

Comment: Well I tried that and no text will apear

Comment: i have edited it. It will work now.

Comment: I have fixed it now the code looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="text">
    <input id="password" type="password" value="" size="10" maxlength="15">
</div>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Enter">

var passbox = document.getElementById("password");

function enterPwerd() {
    var pass = passbox.value;

    if (pass === 'bacon') {
        alert("BACON is so good.")
    } else {
        alert("You put the wrong password you taco biscuit!")
    }
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", enterPwerd, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Lj2EV/)

Comment: Here is the fixed code now:

Comment: Oh? ok. But the question is closed and you choose another answer.

Comment: Well you need to give the text box and button an ID then get the ID and make display = "none"

Comment: Are you sure you are posting your comments on the correct answer?

Comment: Yes I am sure you need to make give the button and text boxes an ID then put this in the if and else statments:

Comment: document.getElementById('textbutton').style.display = "none"

Comment: I'm sorry, you have completely lost me. None of this seems connected to the original question or the answer that I provided.